# Hibernate unproxy on cast or instanceOf

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an inherited entity like so:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Animal {}

@DiscriminatorValue("Dog")
public class Dog extends Animal{ private String name; }

@DiscriminatorValue("Cat")
public class Cat extends Animal { private String color;}
```

The animal is used in other instances like this:

```
@Entity
public class Bowl {

private Animal belongsTo;

}
```

When I load the Bowl from the database, I want to select different things depending if it `belongsTo` is a Cat or a Dog.

But `(bowl.getBelongsTo() instanceOf Cat)` does not work because at this point `bowl.getBelongsTo()` is neither of class Cat nor Dog, it is of class `Animal$HibernateProxy`.

For just checking the instanceOf, `Hibernate.getClass()` would be a good option (although developers might still forget about using this and the error only becomes present at runtime).
But often times we want to cast like this:

```
// check or just assert that it is a Dog

Dog d = (Dog) bowl.getBelongsTo();
```

This results in an error because the HibernateProxy object cannot be cast to `Dog`.

**Question:**
Is there a smart way to tell Hibernate to unproxy itself when it is needed for casting?

Comment: I don't understand why `Hibernate.unproxy(proxy, Dog.class)` doesn't do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your question! It does exactly what I need, but I don't think I should have to do it. I also don't have to explicitly call `Hibernate.unproxy()` if I want to access a value of the `dog` variable. That's why I thought there might be a smarter solution to this.

Comment: You have to do it when the association is fetched lazily, since we cannot determine the type of the associated entity without fetching it. On the other hand, if you fetch the association eagerly (which you usually *should*), then you don't need to do it.

Comment: That's the thing, in most cases (like accessing some variable inside `dog`) Hibernate just unproxies the object itself. But somehow casting the variable is no such case. And I just wanted to know why. I know how I could fix it, but especially with the Single-Table-Inheritance pattern I used, I could see this as a problem that may affect many. 
Not sure I agree with "you usually should fetch associations eagerly".

Comment: Well I just explained why. Because Hibernate doesn't know the concrete type until it fetches the association. There's no imaginable way to "fix" this, it's just a completely logical and inevitable restriction we have to live with.

Comment: Never looked at it from that point, you're right. There is no way for Hibernate to know that `instanceof` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the need to use `Hibernate.unproxy()` by fetching the association eagerly using a query with `join fetch`, or whatever.